# Botan pipe failbit exception

Tags: c++, botan

When I followed the instructions in Botan document Pipe/Filter Message Processing, I was faced with an unexpected failbit error.

My code is very simple:

```
ifstream in("2.txt", ios::binary);
ofstream out("2.enc", ios::binary); 
AutoSeeded_RNG rng;
SymmetricKey key(rng, 16); // a random 128-bit key
InitializationVector iv(rng, 16); // a random 128-bit IV

Pipe pipe(get_cipher("AES-128/CBC/CTS", key, iv, ENCRYPTION), new DataSink_Stream(out));
pipe.start_msg();
in >> pipe;
pipe.end_msg();
cout << in.fail() << endl;
```

It would always output 1, since the failbit is always set to 1.

Is this a bug or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how C++ input streams work; when a read is attempted past EOF, [*failbit* and *eofbit* are set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

We can see from the documented Botan code that [`operator>>` will throw an exception if only *failbit* is set after extraction is attempted](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/namespaceBotan.html#acdc9f284a06017324c71df9f66c32a23); in short, you have nothing to worry about here. The computer is just telling you that you consumed all the input data<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is not solely what *eofbit* means in the strictest sense, but the way that Botan's `operator>>` works (reading as much as it can) requires an attempted read past EOF; otherwise, it wouldn't know when to stop!</sub>